# Unable to show link with echo with an anchor tag in the variable in phtml file

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.9

In a phtml file, I want to display a variable `$value` with `echo`.

This value sometimes contains `<a href>` tag. In that case, the link is not getting printed. It is printing the html tag itself.

I tried to put it like the below ones. But, it still doesn't work. Any ideas please? Thanks.

```
echo $this->htmlEscape($value)
echo $this->htmlEscape(htmlspecialchars($value))
```

Comment: Its the whole thing in text format like  <a href="xxxxxxxxx" target="_blank">YYYYY</a>

Comment: Remove the escaping:  `echo $value;`. Escaping converts your angle brackets to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, so the HTML code is displayed instead of interpreted.

Comment: Can you show us the data, and what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlentities() function to print html tag.

Comment: That just makes < as &lt; etc . But the link is still not printed. :(